# How to Manage Text OverFlow in Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, text-processing

How to Manage Text OverFlow in Pillow If We Have Starting Pixel or Ending Pixel of Certain Place And I Want To Put Text On That Place Then How To Put It?

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

records = df.to_dict(orient='record')


ID_Font = ImageFont.truetype("Arial.ttf", size=40)
H_Font = ImageFont.truetype("Ms.ttf", size=40)
font2 = ImageFont.truetype("Calibri.ttf", size=33)
font3 = ImageFont.truetype("Calibri.ttf", size=35)


def generate_card(data):
    template = Image.open("template.png")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(template)

    draw.text((1455, 537), str(data['id']), font=ID_Font, fill='black')
    draw.text((375, 534), str(data['id']), font=ID_Font, fill='black')
    draw.text((328, 255), data['name'], font=font2, fill='black')
    draw.text((250, 255), data['hname'], font=H_Font, fill='black')
    draw.text((1652, 241), data['Address'], font=font3, fill='black')
    draw.text((580, 307), data['dob'], font=font3, fill='black')
    return template


    for record in records:
         card = generate_card(record)
         card.save(f"cards/{record['name']}.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

In a situation like this you can keep track of the dimensions of each text string and where you're about to place it, probably on a word-by-word basis. If you see it will go off the target area, you can wrap it to the next line. If you do the math, you can get exactly what you want.

An alternative is to use a different text package that will do all the word wrapping (line breaks) for you. Then, when you've finished preprocessing the text (by inserting line breaks where necessary), you can place the text all in one shot.

Programming is all about logic. Deciding how to do something is usually the harder part. Once the logic is good, the coding should follow naturally.

In your case, you may just want to wrap draw.text() with a "helper function". You pass it the coordinates of where you want to put the text, and also the text string and the dimensions of the target area, and it can put the text where you've asked if it will fit, or it can put it at the beginning (or some other offset into) the next line. The function would then return something to let you know what it did, perhaps a boolean to indicate whether it put it on the requested location or at the beginning of the next line, or it might return the placed coordinates and then you'd check those coordinates to see if the text was placed on the requested line or the next line (by the Y value).

Comment: pixel = [ [1658,240] , [2079,402] ]
text = """Simplicity--the art of maximizing the amount of work not done--is essential."""
def generate_card(data):
    template = Image.open("template.png")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(template)
    draw.text((1455, 537), str(data['id']), font=ID_Font, fill='black')
    draw.text((375, 534), str(data['id']), font=ID_Font, fill='black')
    draw.text((328, 255), data['name'], font=font2, fill='black')
    draw.text((1652, 241), data['Address'], font=font3, fill='black')
    return template